# Facebook Graph API error #272

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I'm building an application that needs to read Facebook ads information and I'm running into an issue, which to me seems strange.

When I access the campaigns for my adaccounts using https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/me?fields=adaccounts{campaigns} it works and I can see the campaigns and their properties. 
When I change the request to access the campaign to https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/[campaign_id] it results in an error which says:

(#272) This Ads API call requires the user to be admin of the application. User is not admin or developer of this application.

I can see the properties of the campaigns using "me" as the first Node in the request. 
Any idea why can't I access the campaign using a request where the campaign is the first Node? What could be the reason behind this problem?

Comment: `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/` is just the base URL of the API, that would not access any object specifically. Is there something missing after this in your post, or did you actually try to request "nothing" and are wondering why that doesn't work?

Comment: There was an problem in the URL that I had posted (fixed it now). The URL I'm trying to access is https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/[campaign_id]

Comment: What kind of access token are you using?

Comment: I'm using an user access token and since the same token has access in the first case, I would think that it's not a permission issue.

Comment: @CBroe Any idea?

Comment: Try going to `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<APPID>/settings/advanced/` and In the `Authorized Ad Account IDs` try setting the ad account id

Comment: @Albert, any update on this?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Still no solution...

Answer (score 0):

I've read many posts on this and I found that this is most likely a permissions issue or token issue.

First of all, could you please try to login as the user, and then go to Facebook Ads Manager or Power Editor to check if the user still has permissions on the account?

If you can still see and edit the ad account, then you would need to report this issue at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/ instead.

This could also be one of the explanation.

This may be due to your ad account is inactive or in a bad standing. Additionally if your access level of your ad account is in development level these types of errors may occur. please go through what's mentioned on the doc [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access) If you upgrade your account to basic or standard access levels this will be solved.

On development access level only end to end workflows are suggested. The following text is extracted from facebook documentation.

> The development access level is designed for development purposes and
>   is ideal for people who are just starting to build out their tool. In
>   this level, you would not yet have customers using your tool. This
>   level is open to all developers, and is intended to build out
>   end-to-end workflows on the API before you get full permissions.